# coping one row of multidimentional array to another array with constraint using c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, copy, constraints

```
int[,] arr1 = new int[2,6];
arr1[0, 0] = 100;
arr1[1, 0] = 200;
int[,] arr2= {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}};
```

I want to copy each row from arr2 to arr1 **without using loop**. 
**Constraint is like coping data start for arr2 is index 0 and arr1 is index 1.**

before implement logic arr1 is like

```
Row1: 100,0,0,0,0,0
Row2: 200,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want output **without using loop** for coping from arr2 to arr1 is like

```
Row1: 100,1,2,3,4,5
Row2: 200,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: why not using loop? o_O

Comment: `arr1[0,1] = arr2[0,0]`.... and so on, no loops! :P just kidding of course, why should you not use loops?

Comment: Using loop this will take more time for execution. I want to reduce execution time so i want to implement in single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Without any loops you are constrained to hard coding this.
Any functions or libraries you can call to do it for you will use some sort of looping in the background.

As for the hard coding you are looking at something as simple as:

```
arr1[0,1] = arr2[0,0];
arr1[0,2] = arr2[0,1];
```

etc...

and

```
arr1[1,1] = arr2[1,0];
arr1[1,2] = arr2[1,1];
```

etc...

Comment: You could potentially use CopyTo, but this requires reformatting everything into a 1D array first and then building it all back up (again hard coded without loops).

Comment: if is it possible using LINQ also then tell me. I want to perform this operation in single statement. i know by using 1-D array but searching logic by use of 2-D array.

Comment: If you use LINQ it will simply implement a loop for you and potentially add extra overhead. A well constructed loop should not take more execution time, as it will eventually compile down to less assembly code anyway, and will probably run faster. I can produce performance reports on both methods if you would like?